# Early return not working in integration tests in elixir/phoenix

Tags: elixir, integration-testing, phoenix-framework, early-return

I am totally new to Elixir, but when using Node we do a lot of early returns, but I'm having some problems to make an early-return-like code work in my integration tests. This is my problem:

I have this method in my controller that receives a JSON as param, I need to validate if the JSON contains some properties (key and type), if it doesn't I want to send an error to the client without the need to execute the rest of the method. This works perfectly when I make a request using Insomnia or Postman, but it doesn't work in my integration tests. The code below the conditional executes even when the conditional is falsy.

This is my method:

```
def create(conn, body) do
    if !PayeeContext.check_for_required_fields(body), do: conn
      |> send_resp(400, "Please provide Key and Type parameters")

    %{"key" => key} = body
    %{"type" => type} = body

    validation_func = PayeeContext.validation_map(type)

    case validation_func.(key) do
      {:ok, _} ->
        conn |> send_resp(200, "Request created successfully")
      {:error, message} -> conn |> send_resp(400, message)
    end
  end
```

and this is my test

```
test "returns 400 if Key prop is missing", %{conn: conn} do
      params = %{
        key: "44187221816",
        account: %{
          account_type: "checking_account",
          account_number: "00028363-6",
          branch: "0001"
        },
        owner: %{
          name: "Eve Montalvão"
        }
      }

      response = conn |> post(Routes.payee_path(conn, :create, params))

      assert response.status == 400
    end
```

and my PayeeContext.check_for_required_fields

```
  def check_for_required_fields(fields) do
    Enum.all?(@required_fields, fn field -> Map.has_key?(fields, field) end)
  end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the code from `PayeeContext.check_for_required_fields/1`

Comment: @Everett you're right, done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If-statements are rare in Elixir: pattern matching is more idiomatic.  The forking of execution flow can be hard to follow, and you'll find that "early returns" can be a bit confusing at best, or an anti-pattern at worst.

Consider refactoring your code to do the pattern match in the function arguments. Not only does this eliminate the need for your validation function (because the pattern match will only succeed if those keys are present), it allows you to define multiple clauses of the `create/2` function.  This effectively gives you 2 execution paths: one for cases when the `key` and `type` parameters are present, and another when they are not.

```
def create(conn, %{"key" => key, "type" => type}) do

    validation_func = PayeeContext.validation_map(type)

    case validation_func.(key) do
      {:ok, _} ->
        conn |> send_resp(200, "Request created successfully")
      {:error, message} -> conn |> send_resp(400, message)
    end
end

def create(conn, _) do
  send_resp(conn, 400, "Please provide Key and Type parameters")
end
```

Remember: the more specific matches must go first -- execution will be dispatched to the first function where a match succeeds.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! It's very hard to remember that pattern matching resolves a lot of things when you are used to a completely different language like Node. But I'll keep that in mind. Thank you @Everett :D

Comment: Yeah, pattern matches are the go-to solution for most problems in Elixir.  To point out how your original code was running: when your if block ran this: `send_resp(400, "Please...")`, that block returned a modified version of the `conn` variable... but it never got stored.  The execution would continue down to the end of the `create` function.

If you really wanted to branch there, you'd need to put the entire rest of your `create` function inside an `else` block.  You need to guarantee that the `create` function returns the modified `conn` object.

Comment: While this is definitely the way to go, and this answer is absolutely correct, it’s worth mentioning that one still can early return from plugin pipelines with [`Plug.Conn.halt/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html?#halt/1). That said, adding `|> halt()` after the top `send_resp(400)` would also work. *But* the proper way is described in this answer :)